# C# populate combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

How can I populate a combo box in C# with an array that my display member is the value of array and the value member is the array key?

```
string[] RelayTypeArray = new string[4]; 
RelayTypeArray[0] = null; 
RelayTypeArray[1] = "Boiler"; 
RelayTypeArray[2] = "Valve"; 
RelayTypeArray[3] = "Pump"; 
cmb_RelayType.DataSource = RelayTypeArray; 
cmb_RelayType.DisplayMember = RelayTypeArray; 
cmb_RelayType.ValueMember = ?????
```

Comment: show the array first. Basically ur code..

Comment: You can use `DataBinding` e.g `ControlID.DataSource=array;`

Comment: Diane Post your code in the section where you posted the initial question

Comment: AVD What about the display member and value member?

Comment: Posted an explanation, hoping this will help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use your array as it is...

```
string[] RelayTypeArray = new string[4]; 
RelayTypeArray[0] = null; 
RelayTypeArray[1] = "Boiler"; 
RelayTypeArray[2] = "Valve"; 
RelayTypeArray[3] = "Pump"; 
cmb_RelayType.DataSource = RelayTypeArray;
```

if you want the text: `cmb_RelayType.SelectedValue`

if you want the index: `cmb_RelayType.SelectedIndex`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I set the Selected Index on page load? I tried  cmb_RelayType.SelectedIndex = (int)(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[1][1]); but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you can set the SelectedIndex anytime after you have populated the items in the combo. To test, just try `cmb_RelayType.SelectedIndex = 3;`

Comment: I tried that and got this error : InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Parameter name: SelectedIndex

Comment: Thanks Paul for your wise words. Can you seem to crack this problem?

Comment: that should have worked, providing you had at least four options in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

If you just put a `string[]` as `DataSource` you don't have to define a `DataMember` or a `ValueMember`.
You can simply get the `myComboBox.SelectedValue` and `myComboBox.SelectedIndex`.

The `DataMember`-Property just describes a property to display in the ComboBox of the type you set as `DataSource`.

For example you set a List of

```
class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

as `DataSource` and want the box to display the `Name` property you have to set

```
myComboBox.DataMember = "Name";
```

The `ValueMember` is an "invisible" property for the GUI where you can store values for later use, for example:

```
myComboBox.ValueMember = "Id"
```

So if someone chooses one item by its displayed `Name` you can get the `Id` from the `Value` (don't know the propper name by heart) property of the `ComboBoxItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class and bind it's collection:

```
class RelayType
{
    private int m_Index;
    private string m_Value;

    public RelayType(int index, string value)
    {
        m_Index = index;
        m_Value = value;
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get { return m_Index; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return m_Value; }
    }
}

var relayTypeCol = new List<RelayType>(); 
relayTypeCol.Add(new RelayType(0, ""));
relayTypeCol.Add(new RelayType(1, "Boiler"));
relayTypeCol.Add(new RelayType(2, "Valve"));
relayTypeCol.Add(new RelayType(3, "Pump"));

cmb_RelayType.DataSource = relayTypeCol; 
cmb_RelayType.DisplayMember = "Value"; 
cmb_RelayType.ValueMember = "Index";
```